# Unable to deploy angular code with base-href /app-name/ on PCF

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-config, pcf

We are trying to deploy our angular code to PCF on Nginx buildpack. The app was working fine until I added **--base-href /app-name/** in build command of the code.

Below is the build command that we use in Jenkins Pipeline.

`node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=dev --base-href /app-name/ --output-path=dist/app-name`

After this I was getting the error as.
[image]
Below is the changes that I tried in NgInx conf file

`location /app-name/ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/app-name;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app-name/index.html;
}`

Probably I'm thinking that their is a syntax problem in Nginx Conf file.

Any help on this will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The MIME-Type error means you are hitting the HTML file instead of delevivering the resource you are requesting. What is the directory structure for your application? Where are your JS / CSS files located on disk? The problem is likely to the location and root inside it.

Comment: After the build the file structure looks like dist > app-name > (here is all the files reside)

Comment: All the JS file will be in the same folder where index.html is present.